# How do I find out where a Visualforce page is being used in my Salesforce org?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am fixing soql injection errors in my Salesforce org.  How do I find out where that page is being called from in Salesforce?  I tried looking at the 'Where is this used?" button under setup/Visualforce page/edit/ and it just shows me the test that it is being called from.  I checked the show dependencies and it shows me the controller that it is associated with.  I can't seem to figure how I can access the page in Salesforce so I can do a manual test on it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sandbox and try to delete it in there. If page is "properly" used - dependency should block the delete. Can be custom VF tab, button, link, embed on page layout as iframe... Can even be in community or Site as a login page for example.

If you have the project in git or sfdx you could try searching for page's API name.

But pages can be also accessed freestyle, in classic UI you used to just /apex/vfpagename in the address bar. In lightning it's bit more complex but doable for a determined user.

If you want to block access while you fix it - remove right to use the page from profiles / permission sets.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/12672/799

https://lightning-configuration.salesforce.com used to give some info about VF pages usage (count of hits I think) and there's whole Event Monitoring module paid extra (standalone or as part of Salesforce Shield) too